# Closed Contour Integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

My professor gave us the the following integral to solve
$$\oint_{C}\frac{z^{15}}{(z^2+1)^3(z^4-2)^2}dz \ \ , \ \ \vert{z}\vert=2 \ \ , \ \ \text{0 is the centre}$$
I know that the poles are $z=\pm{i}$ (m=$3$) for $(z^2+1)^3$ and the 4 simple poles that are the roots of $(z^4-2)$. My question is if i have to find all the residues and calculate it or if the integral is $0$ if the function is analytic.

Comment: The function isn't analytic due to the presence of poles inside C. Therefore, you have to compute the different residues... Beware: the 4 roots of $z^4=2$ are double poles...

Comment: You could compute all residues and add them. You could also consider the function $f(1/z)$, for $z\neq0$, where $f$ is the integrand.

Comment: plop invites you implicitly to consider the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity). Have you seen this concept and its use ?

Comment: @JeanMarie you are right, those are double poles. I haven't seen this concept. Could you explain to me how to use it?

Comment: In this case, use @plop suggestion.  Make the change of variables $w=1/z$ to get an integral $$\oint\frac{dw}{w^3(w^2+1)^3(2w^4-1)^2}$$ around the curve $|w|=1/2$.  (Watch which direction you go around that circle.) Now you have fewer residues to compute.  After you do a few of these, you will see how you can instead compute "residue at infinity" without explicitly changing variables.

Comment: The integral GEdgar has given you is explicited in the Wikipedia reference I gave.

Comment: If it can help, you should find that the sum of residues is $3$.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for your help. This is a much easier integral to calculate than the first one.